# how to config a spdy proxy with httpclient(or others) on android platform

Tags: https, proxy, spdy

Recently I am trying to setup a spdy proxy for android platform as follows:

[client] ----spdy---- [spdy proxy] ----http---- [squid] ----...

I try to use shrpx for the spdy proxy but can not configure it on the client end, any one has suggestions how to work it out? Is HttpClient possible for this scenario? Example codes would be appreciated.